# An execuatable somtimes starts in 32-bit mode rather than 64-bit

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have three Windows 2016 servers running within Azure with an odd issue where when a particular service starts it sometimes starts in 32bit mode and sometimes in 64 bit. It should be 64 bit.

The service is "Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server" "Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Server.exe"

If the services starts as 32bit it causes issues, restarting the service then causes it to start in 64 bit mode and fixes the issues. The issue only happens if the service starts with Windows, manually starting or restarting the service manually always causes it to start as 64bit

Very odd, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion, not an answer, but reconfiguring the service for delayed start *might* help, or at least reduce the frequency with which the problem occurs.